# In what amounts is beer beneficial to ones health?

Tags: health

As pointed out in [Are there any medicinal uses for beer?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/278/are-there-any-medicinal-uses-for-beer), beer has some beneficial effects on ones health.
Assuming a beer with average alcohol level and an average, healthy adult, how much would be a healthy amount to drink on regular bases?
Also, how would the alcohol influence the health benefits?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about medical advice and should be talked about with a doctor rather than randoms on the net.

Comment: Is there a defined rule for what is medical advice and what are just general health tips yet? If not, we should try to work out a concept on meta.

Comment: Since there is nothing akin to a USRDA "recommended daily allowances" for beer, I would suggest this is more of a discussion filled with debate points than anything "answerable". Being that this site isn't exactly about heath and nutrition, I'm going to close this as largely off topic for *this* site.

Comment: At work and can't source this at the moment. There are studies about beer that relate darker beers (porters and such) to reduced risk of colon cancer in men when drank in 8oz servings once a day (think red wine and heart disease). However all of these kinds of studies and topics are health related topics and would be better served on a nutrition or medical SE site.